# unable to insert in my mysql database and the connection is good

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

I've Server Mysql in my Windows server 2008.
PHP works and I test my connection with my db and everythings seems ok
Exemple with testmysql.php:

```
<?PHP
//remember to change the password to whatever you set
//it to in mysql instance configuration

//first parameter is server name, 2nd username 'root', 3rd is password
$rst = @mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","admin");

if (!$rst){
     echo( "<p>Unable to connect to database manager.</p>");
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     exit();
} else {
  echo("<p>Successfully Connected to MySQL Database Manager!</p>");
}

if (! @mysql_select_db("fullcalendar") ){
     echo( "<p>Unable to  connect database...</p>");
     exit();
} else {
  echo("<p>Successfully Connected to Database 'fullcalendar'!</p>");
}
?>
```

result:
Successfully Connected to MySQL Database Manager!

Successfully Connected to Database 'fullcalendar'!

and my file db.config.php

```
    <?php
/*
 * Created on 17-okt-2011
 * author Paul Wolbers
 */

function database_connect() {
    global $obj_db;

    if($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == 'localhost:3306') {
        $str_hostname = 'localhost:3306';
        $str_username = 'root';
        $str_password = 'admin';
        $str_database = 'fullcalendar';
    } else {
        $str_hostname = 'localhost:3306';
        $str_username = 'root';
        $str_password = 'admin';
        $str_database = 'fullcalendar';
    }

    $obj_db = mysqli_connect($str_hostname, $str_username, $str_password, $str_database);
    if($obj_db === FALSE) {
        $error= "Database connection failed";
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    mysqli_set_charset( $obj_db , 'utf8' );
}
?>
```

my cal_events.php

```
<?php
/*
 * Created on 17-okt-2011
 * author Paul Wolbers
 *
 */
require_once '../include/default.inc.php';
//require_once '../config/db.config.php';
//database_connect();



// test with session user_id
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;

switch($_GET['action']) {
    case 'add':
        addEvent();
        break;
    case 'start':
        getEvents();
        break;
//  case 'get_agenda':
//      getEventsStartingToday();
//      break;
//  case 'update_title':
//      updateEventTitle();
//      break;
    case 'update':
        updateEvent();
        break;
    case 'resize':
        resizeEvent();
        break;
    case 'del':
        deleteEvent();
        break;
}

function getEvents() {
    global $obj_db;

    $str_query = 'SELECT *, event_id as id, concat_ws(" ",date_start,time_start) as start,concat_ws(" ",date_end,time_end) as end FROM events ';
    $obj_result = mysqli_query($obj_db, $str_query);

    while ($arr_line = mysqli_fetch_array($obj_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $arr_line['allDay']     = $arr_line['allDay'] == 0 ? false : true;
        $arr_line['editable']   = $arr_line['user_id'] == $_SESSION['user_id'] ? true : false;

        $arr_content[] = $arr_line;

    }

    echo json_encode($arr_content);
}

function getDaysBetween($sStartDate, $sEndDate){
    $sStartDate     = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($sStartDate));
    $sEndDate       = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($sEndDate));
    $aDays[]        = $sStartDate;
    $sCurrentDate   = $sStartDate;

    while($sCurrentDate < $sEndDate){
        $sCurrentDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($sCurrentDate)));
        $aDays[] = $sCurrentDate;
    }
    return $aDays;
}

function getEventsStartingToday() {
    global $obj_db;

    $str_query = 'SELECT * , event_id AS id, concat_ws( " ", date_start, time_start ) AS
                    START , concat_ws( " ", date_end, time_end ) AS
                    END FROM events WHERE date_start >= DATE( NOW( ) )
                    OR (
                    date_start < DATE( NOW( ) )
                    AND date_end > DATE( NOW( ) )
                    )
                    ORDER BY date_start ';
    $obj_result = mysqli_query($obj_db, $str_query);

    while ($arr_line = mysqli_fetch_array($obj_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $arr_content[] = $arr_line;

    }
//print_r($arr_content);
    $arr_result = array();

    foreach($arr_content as $event) {
        // meerdaags event
        if($event['date_end'] != $event['date_start']) {

            $days_in_between = getDaysBetween($event['date_start'], $event['date_end']);
            foreach($days_in_between as $day) {
                $arr_result[$day][] = $event;
            }


        } else {
            $arr_result[$event['date_start']][] = $event;
        }
    }

    $obj_smarty = new Smarty();
    $obj_smarty->compile_dir = '../templates_c/';

    $obj_smarty->assign('items', $arr_result);

    $obj_smarty->display(FULLCAL_DIR.'/view/agenda.html');
}

function addEvent() {

    global $obj_db;
    if(!isset($_POST['date_end'])) {
        $_POST['date_end'] = $_POST['date_start'];
    }
    if(!isset($_POST['color'])) {
        $_POST['color'] = '';
    }
    $str_query = 'INSERT INTO events (title, user_id, color, date_start, time_start, date_end, time_end, allday) ' .
            'VALUES ("'.$_POST['title'].'",
                    '.$_SESSION['user_id'].',
                    "'.$_POST['color'].'",
                    "'.date('Y-m-d', $_POST['date_start']).'",
                    "'.date('H:i:s', $_POST['date_start']).'",
                    "'.date('Y-m-d', $_POST['date_end']).'",
                    "'.date('H:i:s', $_POST['date_end']).'"'.
                    (date('H:i:s', $_POST['date_start']) == '00:00:00' && date('H:i:s', $_POST['date_end']) == '00:00:00' ? ' ,1' : ' ,0').')';
    $obj_result = mysqli_query($obj_db, $str_query);

    $str_query = 'SELECT *, event_id as id, concat_ws(" ",date_start,time_start) as start,concat_ws(" ",date_end,time_end) as end ' .
            'FROM events WHERE event_id = '.mysqli_insert_id($obj_db);
    $obj_result = mysqli_query($obj_db, $str_query);
    $arr_event = mysqli_fetch_array($obj_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $arr_event['allDay']    = $arr_event['allDay'] == 0 ? false : true;
    $arr_event['editable']  = $arr_event['user_id'] == $_SESSION['user_id'] ? true : false;

    echo json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'event'=>$arr_event ));exit;

}

//function updateEventTitle() {
//  global $obj_db;

//  $str_query = 'UPDATE events SET title = "'.$_POST['title'].'" WHERE event_id = '.$_POST['event_id'].' AND user_id = '. $_SESSION['user_id'];
//  $obj_result = mysqli_query($obj_db, $str_query);

//  echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));exit;
//}

function updateEvent() {
    global $obj_db;

    $str_query = 'UPDATE events SET date_start = "'.date('Y-m-d', $_POST['date_start']).'" ' .
            (isset($_POST['title']) ? ', title = "'.$_POST['title'].'"' : '').
                (isset($_POST['color']) && $_POST['color'] != 'undefined' ? ', color = "'.$_POST['color'].'"' : '').
            ', date_end = "'.date('Y-m-d', $_POST['date_end']).'" ' .
            ', time_start = "'.date('H:i:s', $_POST['date_start']).'" ' .
            ', time_end = "'.date('H:i:s', $_POST['date_end']).'" ' .
            ((isset($_POST['allDay']) && $_POST['allDay']) || (date('H:i:s', $_POST['date_start']) == '00:00:00' && date('H:i:s', $_POST['date_end']) == '00:00:00') ? ' ,allDay = 1' : ' ,allDay = 0').
                ' WHERE event_id = '.$_POST['event_id'].' AND user_id = '. $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $obj_result = mysqli_query($obj_db, $str_query);


    $str_query = 'SELECT *, event_id as id, concat_ws(" ",date_start,time_start) as start,concat_ws(" ",date_end,time_end) as end ' .
            'FROM events WHERE event_id = '.$_POST['event_id'];
    $obj_result = mysqli_query($obj_db, $str_query);
    $arr_event = mysqli_fetch_array($obj_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $arr_event['allDay']    = $arr_event['allDay'] == 0 ? false : true;
    $arr_event['editable']  = $arr_event['user_id'] == $_SESSION['user_id'] ? true : false;

    echo json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'event'=>$arr_event ));exit;
}

function resizeEvent() {
    global $obj_db;

    $str_query = 'UPDATE events SET date_start = "'.date('Y-m-d', $_POST['date_start']).'" ' .
            ', date_end = "'.date('Y-m-d', $_POST['date_end']).'" ' .
            ', time_start = "'.date('H:i:s', $_POST['date_start']).'" ' .
            ', time_end = "'.date('H:i:s', $_POST['date_end']).'" ' .
                ' WHERE event_id = '.$_POST['event_id'].' AND user_id = '. $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $obj_result = mysqli_query($obj_db, $str_query);



    echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));exit;
}

function deleteEvent() {
    global $obj_db;

    $str_query = 'DELETE FROM events WHERE event_id = '.$_POST['event_id'].' AND user_id = '. $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $obj_result = mysqli_query($obj_db, $str_query);

    echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));exit;
}
?>
```

my index.php

```
<?php
/*
 * Created on 17-okt-2011
 * author Paul Wolbers
 */

require_once 'include/default.inc.php';

if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
    switch($_GET['action']) {
        case 'agenda':
            showAgenda();
            break;
        case 'agenda_widget':
            showAgenda(true);
            break;
        case 'timeline':
            showTimeline();
            break;
        case 'get_timeline_events':
            getTimelineEvents();
            break;

  }
} else {
    $obj_smarty->display(FULLCAL_DIR.'/view/cal.html');
}

function getDaysBetween($sStartDate, $sEndDate){
    $sStartDate     = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($sStartDate));
    $sEndDate       = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($sEndDate));
    $aDays[]        = $sStartDate;
    $sCurrentDate   = $sStartDate;

    while($sCurrentDate < $sEndDate){
        $sCurrentDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($sCurrentDate)));
        $aDays[] = $sCurrentDate;
    }
    return $aDays;
}

function showAgenda($bln_widget=false) {
    global $obj_db;

    $str_query = 'SELECT * , event_id AS id, concat_ws( " ", date_start, time_start ) AS
                    START , concat_ws( " ", date_end, time_end ) AS
                    END FROM events WHERE date_start >= DATE( NOW( ) )
                    OR (
                    date_start < DATE( NOW( ) )
                    AND date_end >= DATE( NOW( ) )
                    )
                    ORDER BY date_start ';
    $obj_result = mysqli_query($obj_db, $str_query);

    while ($arr_line = mysqli_fetch_array($obj_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $arr_content[] = $arr_line;

    }
//print_r($arr_content);
    $arr_result = array();

    foreach($arr_content as $event) {
        // meerdaags event
        if($event['date_end'] != $event['date_start']) {

            $days_in_between = getDaysBetween($event['date_start'], $event['date_end']);
            foreach($days_in_between as $day) {
                if(strtotime($day) >= strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))) {
           $arr_result[$day][] = $event;
        }

            }


        } else {
            $arr_result[$event['date_start']][] = $event;
        }
    }
    //print_r($days_in_between);exit;
    //print_r($arr_result);

    $obj_smarty = new Smarty();
    $obj_smarty->compile_dir = 'templates_c/';

    $obj_smarty->assign('items', $arr_result);

    if($bln_widget) {
        $obj_smarty->display(FULLCAL_DIR.'/view/agenda_small.html');
    } else {
        $obj_smarty->display(FULLCAL_DIR.'/view/agenda.html');
    }
}

function showTimeline() {


    $obj_smarty = new Smarty();
    $obj_smarty->compile_dir = 'templates_c/';

    //$obj_smarty->assign('items', $arr_result);

    $obj_smarty->display(FULLCAL_DIR.'/view/timeline.html');

}

function getTimelineEvents() {
//[{{
//    "id": "jshist",
//    "title": "A little history of JavaScript",
//    "focus_date": "2001-01-01 12:00:00",
//    "initial_zoom": "43",
//    "timezone": "-07:00",
//    "events": [
//    {
//      "id": "jshist-01",
//      "title": "Mocha - Live Script",
//      "description": "JavaScript was originally developed by Brendan Eich of
//                Netscape under the name Mocha. LiveScript was the official name for the
//                language when it first shipped in beta releases of Netscape Navigator 2.0
//                in September 1995",
//      "startdate": "1995-04-01 12:00:00",
//      "enddate": "1995-04-01 12:00:00",
//      "date_display": "month",
//      "link": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript",
//      "importance": 40,
//      "icon":"square_blue.png"
//     },
//     {
//      "id": "jshist-02",
//      "title": "JavaScript is Born",
//      "description": "LiveScript is Renamed JavaScript in a joint
//                announcement with Netscape and Sun Microsystems",
//      "startdate": "1995-12-04 12:00:00",
//      "enddate": "1995-12-04",
//      "date_display": "day",
//      "link": "http: //en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript",
//      "importance": 50,
//      "icon":"triangle_orange.png"
//    }
//  ]
//  }
//]
    global $obj_db;

    $arr_content = array("id"=> "jshist",
        "title"=> "test",
        "focus_date"=> "2012-01-01 12:00:00",
        "initial_zoom"=> "20",
        "timezone"=> "+01:00"
        );

    $str_query = 'SELECT *, event_id as id, concat_ws(" ",date_start,time_start) as startdate,concat_ws(" ",date_end,time_end) as enddate FROM events ';
    $obj_result = mysqli_query($obj_db, $str_query);

    while ($arr_line = mysqli_fetch_array($obj_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $arr_line['importance'] = 20;
        $arr_events[] = $arr_line;

    }

    $arr_content['events'] = $arr_events;
    echo json_encode(array($arr_content));

}
?>
```

Comment: well .. you could start by removing all the `@` symbols which suppress errors. Also, why the hell you mix `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*` APIs ?

Comment: where are you inserting ? paste your code

Comment: @tereško: Clearly no errors are being suppressed - the return codes are being tested and the output indicates both calls succeeded.

Comment: @tereško The first piece of code is a test case, so that's no his actual code I think (still weird to do a test with mysql when you're working with mysqli.. But oh well). The second code is where we should be looking I guess. (BTW. dont get the if/else statement there, why declare 2 of the same things?)

Comment: @Bono: Looks like, in the future, he will be switching between development & live db depending on whether the server is being accessed locally?  Just a guess.

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 0):

You have commented-out the lines at the start of `cal_events.php` which connect to your database:

```
//require_once '../config/db.config.php';
//database_connect();
```

Without them, functions like `addEvent()` which use the `$obj_db` variable won't work, as it won't have been defined.

Comment: thank you I will try I still have a problem on the way:
require_once '.. / include / default.inc.php';
require_once '.. / config / db.config.php';
I had not seen!
I go here and I am the post without fault. promised;)

Comment: @leerickx: Are you actually providing `action=add` in the querystring?  Perhaps best to create a `default` case to your `switch` statement in order to catch situations where no `action` is matched.

Comment: What I do not understand is why my connection to the air as functional if I change my file db.config.php, I know the fact. On my local machine (easyphp) everything works. is on the server that it does not work.

Comment: Well eggyal Sorry for all. The problems is the format date and no my connection. If I use an sql query and command insert into table... with the date 2012-05-31 it works. How can I do an insert date with the format 31/05/212 and with mysql ? Thanks

Comment: @leerickx: Use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function: e.g. `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('31/05/2012', '%d/%m/%Y'))`.

Comment: Unbelievable it still does not on my server (it works locally). When I do an insert with a query that works, which means that my connection to the db is ok. The event is displayed correctly in my calendar. I can even do an update directly with both the date with time. I can also delete the event. It also means that the rights of my folder where the db works. But still no way to do an insert from the calendar ... I really do, I'm completely lost!